# Change link text upon click

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to change a link's text upon a user clicking it.

So far I have attempted -

```
<script src="/Includes/jquery-1.11.0.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[name="LT"]').click(function() {
            $('[name="LT"]').text("Lucas Orchard");
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I've had no luck in getting it to work. I've looked at previous posts on here, and attempted doing a separate binding for the click event as it is within link tags.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you seem to be under the impression that `<script src=..` defines your dependencies. It does not. (Though it would be kind of awesome if it did).

Basically back in the day everyone used to put script tags all on the same page. As applications grew that got to be unmanageable for a variety of reasons so browsers allowed people to reference scripts externally. So a script tag should have either a body or an src tag, not (in 99.9% of cases) both.

In your case this is correct:

```
<script src="/Includes/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[name="LT"]').click(function() {
            $('[name="LT"]').text("Lucas Orchard");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The first script block will create `window.jQuery` and `window.$` (this is the global scope). Then your second script block runs and uses it.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is ignored as you have used `src` attribute for the `script` tag. Use a `script` tag for loading the js file and another for your current code.

Answer (score 0):

What element is `[name="LT"]` by the way?

If it's an `input`, then you'll have to use `.val` instead of `.text`

```
$('[name="LT"]').click(function() {
  $(this).val("Lucas Orchard");
});
```

Comment: The question specifically says it is a link, not an input.